# How to check if a customer has made a warranty claim and a product sale?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know how to check in PostgreSQL to see if whether or not a customer has made **both** a warranty claim and a product sale.

For example , I have a customer like this.

| CustomerID | OrderID | Product Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1426457 | PRODUCT A |
| ABC123 | 1426458 | WARRANTY CLAIM |

So for this customer. I want to set a column  to **true** that he/she contains both a product sale and a warranty claim.

Whereas a customer like this

| CustomerID | OrderID | Product Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DEF456 | 1426990 | PRODUCT A |
| DEF456 | 1427500 | PRODUCT B |

I want to set a column to **false** becasue he/she does not have a warranty claim.

It does not matter if a customer has made more than two orders. As long as there is a warranty claim and a product sale then I want to set it to true.

Is this possible? So far I have tried various solutions using SQL but to no avail.

***Expected Output :***

| CustomerID | OrderID | Product Name | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1426457 | PRODUCT A | TRUE |
| ABC123 | 1426458 | WARRANTY CLAIM | TRUE |

| CustomerID | OrderID | Product Name | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEF456 | 1426990 | PRODUCT A | FALSE |
| DEF456 | 1427500 | PRODUCT B | FALSE |

Comment: Please provide the expected output. Where should this boolean column appear? At every record of your input (so, twice true and twice false)? Or should it be an aggregate on customerID?

Comment: Okay it should be on every record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=077e688adce9315c494fbdcd65f9a0a8)

```
SELECT
    "CustomerID",
    bool_or("Product Name" = 'WARRANTY CLAIM')
        AND
    bool_or("Product Name" != 'WARRANTY CLAIM')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "CustomerID"
```

With aggregating using `bool_or()` on a `CustomerID` with checking whether a `Product Name` is `WARRENTY CLAIM` or not you return your expected result as aggregate. So, one check should be if there is at least a `WARRENT CLAIM` and at least one without.

---

If you want to get this on every record, you can do this using the [`bool_or()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    *,
    bool_or("Product Name" = 'WARRANTY CLAIM') OVER (PARTITION BY "CustomerID")
        AND
    bool_or("Product Name" != 'WARRANTY CLAIM') OVER (PARTITION BY "CustomerID")
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Okay but what if there is more than two orders per customer? Do I need to have t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 and so on?